# C# and Lotus Notes

Tags: c#, email, lotus-notes

I hope I can get some help on this. Everything I have found online about sending emails through lotus notes using C# is about automating the whole process, But I want to do something (i think) more simple than that. When a user clicks a button, all I want the program to do is open lotus notes on their computer (if it isnt already), open a new email window with the email address and title already filled out. The user then can fill out the body, CCs, and anything else they want, and the click the send button. If this is a repeat question I apologize, but I simply can't seem to find anything. Thanks all.

Comment: is `mailto` registered with lotus notes? i.e. when you click a mail link will it open with lotus notes?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this now with the mailto: protocol for hyperlinks, provided Lotus Notes is registered on the client to handle them.  If it is the main mail client, it likely is setup this way.

```
<a href="mailto:email@domain.com?subject=Hello%20There">
```

Or to launch from a winforms button:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:email@domain.com?subject=Hello%20There");
```

Answer (score 0):

The mailto solution is the easiest by far, however for the record...

Lotus Notes exposes a set of OLE automation classes that you can use to do quite a bit more than just setting the subject. The root of the set of exposed classes is Notes.NotesUIWorkspace. You can find a little documentation for Notes OLE automation [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_USING_NOTES_CLASSES_IN_VISUAL_BASIC.html) and for the NotesUIWorkspace class [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_NOTESUIWORKSPACE_CLASS.html).